# problema de listas en Python

Tags: python-3.x

apenas empiezo en el mundo de la programación y ya hoy me adentre en el tema de listas tengo el siguiente codigo mi pregunta es, se puede hacer lo mismo pero mas legible y con menos codigo?

```
for a in range(1,4):
    nombre=input("\nIngrese nombre: ")
    apellidos=input("Ingrese apellidos: ")
    if a==1:
        usuario1=([nombre,apellidos])
    elif a==2:
        usuario2=([nombre,apellidos])
    else:
        usuario3=([nombre,apellidos])

print(usuario1,usuario2,usuario3)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Dado que estás practicando el uso de listas, puedes usar una lista para almacenar cada usuario y prescindir del condicional, obteniendo así una lista de listas:

```
usuarios = []
for _ in range(3):
    nombre = input("\nIngrese nombre: ")
    apellidos = input("Ingrese apellidos: ")
    usuarios.append([nombre, apellidos])
print(usuarios)
```

> ```
> Ingrese nombre: Maria
> Ingrese apellidos: Malagon
>
> Ingrese nombre: Antonio
> Ingrese apellidos: Garcia
>
> Ingrese nombre: Laura 
> Ingrese apellidos: Uriarte
>
> [['Maria', 'Malagon'], ['Antonio', 'Garcia'], ['Laura', 'Uriarte']]
> ```

Para obtener la lista de cada usuario puedes indizar:

```
print(usuarios[0], usuarios[1], usuarios[2])
```

> ['Maria', 'Malagon'] ['Antonio', 'Garcia'] ['Laura', 'Uriarte']

o iterar sobre ella:

```
for usuario in usuarios:
    print(usuario)
```

> ['Maria', 'Malagon']
>   ['Antonio', 'Garcia']
>   ['Laura', 'Uriarte']

Si quieres también puedes desempaquetar la lista y asignar cada sublista a una variable:

```
usuario1, usuario2, usuario3 = usuarios
```

Al usar una lista en vez de variables te permite modificar de forma dinámica el numero de usuarios a ingresar por ejemplo, con solo modificar las iteraciones del `for`.

Es posible construir la lista también usando [list comprehensions](https://docs.python.org/3.7/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions):

```
usuarios = [[input("\nIngrese nombre: "), input("Ingrese apellidos: ")] for _ in range(3)]
```

o incluso podemos usar una expresión generadora y desempaquetar igual que antes:

```
usuario1, usuario2, usuario3 = ([input("\nIngrese nombre: "), input("Ingrese apellidos: ")] for _ in range(3))
print(usuario1, usuario2, usuario3)
```

pero no merece la pena en este caso la perdida de legibilidad.